# Need help grouping a column that may or may not have the same value but have the same accounts

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, grouping

How do I output data stored in Table 1 so that each like account number has that also has the same CPT group's together but the ones that do not match fall to the bottom of the list?

I have one table: select * from CPTCounts and this is what is displays

*Format (relevant fields only):*

```
account    OriginalCPT       Count          ModifiedCPT  Count
11                           0              71010        1
11         71010             1                           0
2                            0              71010        1
2                            0              71020        9
2                            0              73130        1
2                            0              77800        1  
2          71010             1                           0
2          71020             8                           0
2          73130             1                           0
2          73610             1                           0
2          G0202             4                           0
31         99010             1                           0
31                           0              99010        4
31                           0              99700        2
```

What I want the results to be grouped like is below... and display like this or similar.

```
Account     OriginalCPT    Count      ModifiedCPT   Count
11          71010           1          71010         1
2           71010           1          71010         1
2           71020           8                        0
2           73130           1                        0
2           73610           1                        0
2           G0202           4                        0
31          99010           1          99010         4
31                          0          99700         2
```

I have one table with the values above;

Select * from #CPTCounts

The grouping I am looking for is the Original = Modified CPT and sometimes I will not have a value in one side or the other but most of the times I will have a match.  I would like to place all of the unmatched ones at the bottom of the account.

any suggestions?

I was thinking of creating a second table and joining the two with the account but how do I return each value?

select cpt1.account, cpt1.originalCPT, cpt1.count, cpt2.modifiedcpt, cpt2.count
from #cptcounts cpt1
join #cptcounts cpt2 on cpt1.accont = cpt2.account

but am having trouble with that solution.

Comment: do you have a primary ID key in your table to work with???  If so, what, but otherwise does not look at all like a well-structured table/database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have an exact solution, but perhaps some food for thought at least. The fact that you need either the "original" or the "modified" set of columns makes me think that you need a full outer join rather than a left join. You don't mention which database you are using. In MySql, for example, full joins can be emulated by means of a union of a left and a right join, as in the following:

```
select cpt1.account, cpt1.originalCPT, cpt1.countO, cpt2.modifiedcpt, cpt2.countM
from CPTCounts cpt1
left outer join CPTCounts cpt2 
  on cpt1.account = cpt2.account 
  and cpt1.originalCPT=cpt2.modifiedCPT
where cpt1.account is not null 
  and (cpt1.originalCPT is not null or cpt2.modifiedCPT is not null)
union
select cpt1.account, cpt1.originalCPT, cpt1.countO, cpt2.modifiedcpt, cpt2.countM
from CPTCounts cpt1
right outer join CPTCounts cpt2 
  on cpt1.account = cpt2.account 
  and cpt1.originalCPT=cpt2.modifiedCPT
where cpt2.account is not null 
  and (cpt1.originalCPT is not null or cpt2.modifiedCPT is not null)
order by originalCPT, modifiedCPT, account
```

The ordering brings the non-matching rows to the top, but that seemed a lesser problem than getting the matching to work.

(Your output data is a bit confusing, because the CPT 71020, for example, occurs in both original and modified columns, but you haven't shown it as one of the matching ones in your result set. I'm presuming this is because it is just an example... but if I'm wrong, then I am missing some part of your intention.)

You can play around in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69a93/9).